# error reading text file into new columns of a dataframe using some text editing

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a text file (`0001.txt`) which contains the data as below:

```
<DOC> 
<DOCNO>1100101_business_story_11931012.utf8</DOCNO> 
<TEXT> 

The Telegraph - Calcutta (Kolkata) | Business | Local firms go global
                                                                                                                           6                                                                                      Local firms go global
          JAYANTA ROY CHOWDHURY                              
    New Delhi, Dec. 31: Indian companies are stepping out of their homes to try their luck on foreign shores.         
    Corporate India invested $2.7 billion abroad in the first quarter of 2009-2010 on top of $15.9 billion in 2008-09.         
    Though the first-quarter investment was 15 per cent lower than what was invested in the same period last year, merchant banker Sudipto Bose said, It marks a confidence in a new world order where Indian businesses see themselves as equal to global players.        
    According to analysts, confidence in global recovery, cheap corporate buys abroad and easier rules governing investment overseas had spurred flow of capital and could see total investment abroad top $12 billion this year and rise to $18-20 billion next fiscal.         
    For example, Titagarh Wagons plans to expand abroad on the back of the proposed Asian railroad project.        
    We plan to travel all around the world with the growth of the railroads, said Umesh Chowdhury of Titagarh Wagons.        
    India is full of opportunities, but we are all also looking at picks abroad, said Gautam Mitra, managing director of Indian Structurals Engineering Company.         
    Mitra plans to open a holding company in Switzerland to take his business in structurals to other Asian and African countries.         
    Indian companies created 3 lakh jobs in the US, while contributing $105 billion to the US economy between 2004 and 2007, according to commerce ministry statistics. During 2008-09, Singapore, the Netherlands, Cyprus, the UK, the US and Mauritius together accounted for 81 per cent of the total outward investment.        
    Bose said, And not all of it is organic growth. Much of our investment abroad reflects takeovers and acquisitions.         
    In the last two years, Suzlon acquired Portugals Martifers stake in German REpower Systems for $122 million. McNally Bharat Engineering has bought the coal and minerals processing business of KHD Humboldt Wedag. ONGC bought out Imperial Energy for $2 billion.         
    Indias foreign assets and liabilities today add up to more than 60 per cent of its gross domestic product. By the end of 2008-09, total foreign investment was $67 billion, more than double of that at the end of March 2007.                                                                                                                                       
</TEXT> 
</DOC>
```

Above, all text data is within the HTML code for text i.e.
`<TEXT>`  and  `</TEXT>`.

I want to read it into an R dataframe in a way that there will be four columns and the data should be read as:

```
Title                               Author                 Date      Text   
The Telegraph - Calcutta (Kolkata)  JAYANTA ROY CHOWDHURY  Dec. 31   Indian companies are stepping out of their homes to try their luck on foreign shores. Corporate India invested $2.7 billion abroad in the first quarter of 2009-2010 on top of $15.9 billion in 2008-09. Though the first-quarter investment was 15 percent lower than what was invested in the same period last year, merchant banker Sudipto Bose said, It marks a confidence in a new world order where Indian businesses see themselves as equal to global players.
```

What I was trying to read using **dplyr** and as shown below:

```
 # read text file
 library(dplyr)
 library(readr) 

 dat <- read_csv("0001.txt") %>% slice(-8)

 # print part of data frame 
 head(dat, n=2)
```

In above code, I tried to skip first few lines (which are not important) from the text file that contains the above text and then read it into dataframe.

But I could not get what I was looking for and got confused what I am doing is wrong.

Could someone please help?

Comment: Csv requires some kind of separator separating the fields, normally comma. Each line is a data record consisting of one or more fields. Your data does not seem to have such structure.

Comment: I don't think a data frame is the best structure to to have that data in.  Have you considered a list with `DOCNO` as the names?  Additionally, if this is html you may want to use an html parsing package to help you read it.

Comment: I agree with @RichScriven. If the data is already in html, then an html parsing package would be better for this task. You can try packages like rvest, xml, and/or xml2. But if the data was collected by someone else and is already in text files, then you can also use regex to parse strings, similar to what I've shown below.

Comment: @RyanRunge the Data is collected by someone else and I only get in TEXT format :(  and this is beyond my limits, can not do anything in it. sorry.

Comment: @MadhuSareen - I see. What you're wanting to do is somewhat more complicated than html parsing then. You'd need a regex solution similar to what I've shown below to parse the data. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to read data into R as a data frame or table, the data needs to have a consistent structure maintained by separators. One of the most common formats is a file with comma separated values (CSV).

The data you're working with doesn't have separators though. It's essentially a string with minimally enforced structure. Because of this, it sounds like the question is more related to regular expressions (regex) and data mining than it is to reading text files into R. So I'd recommend looking into those two things if you do this task often.

That aside, to do what you're wanting in this example, I'd recommend reading the text file into R as a single string of text first. Then you can parse the data you want using regex. Here's a basic, rough draft of how to do that:

```
fileName <- "Path/to/your/data/0001.txt"

string <- readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)

df <- data.frame(
      Title=sub("\\s+[|]+(.*)","",string),
      Author=gsub("(.*)+?([A-Z]{2,}.*[A-Z]{2,})+(.*)","\\2",string),
      Date=gsub("(.*)+([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}\\.\\s[0-9]{1,2})+(.*)","\\2",string),
      Text=gsub("(.*)+([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}\\.\\s[0-9]{1,2})+[: ]+(.*)","\\3",string))
```

Output:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Title : chr "The Telegraph - Calcutta (Kolkata)"
 $ Author: chr "JAYANTA ROY CHOWDHURY"
 $ Date  : chr "Dec. 31"
 $ Text  : chr "Indian companies are stepping out of their homes to"| __truncated__
```

The reason why regex can be useful is that it allows for very specific patterns in strings. The downside is when you're working with strings that keep changing formats. That will likely mean some slight adjustments to the regex used.

Comment: Ryan, I see a catch here. Suppose if there is no ` : ` in Text, then "Text" might not get the right text. instead everything will go into either Author or Date, my guess. Can you have a logical check is there is  NO ':' still I get the right TEXT in Text column.

Comment: @MadhuSareen - No problem. We don't need to add much to make that work. All I had to change above was "[:]" to "[: ]" (I added a space). This is similar to a logical check for whether ":" exists in the string. Whether it does or doesn't, the code above should now be able to pick up the main text correctly.

Comment: @MadhuSareen - [The other question you started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384105/error-in-separating-text-from-a-string-using-regex-and-ifelse-condition/46384566#46384566) on SO to answer this question is unnecessary. All of this can be solved with regex expressions and doesn't require if else statements, etc. See [this reference](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) on regex symbols in R.

Comment: I agree Ryan but still wanted to bring this point here becasue there may be issues otherwise. (in fact I am facing such issues). Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: @MadhuSareen - No worries. I remember how it was to start learning regex. It can be confusing at first. So I'm just trying to make tips in the right direction to help you and others learn things more smoothly. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

`read.table( file = ... , sep = "|")` will solve your issue.

Comment: I got the following error `dat <- read.table( file = "0001.txt" , sep = "|") %>% slice(-8)
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 3 elements'